# How to animate an object depending on page scroll position

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently using the following code to display/hide content based on the current scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 409) {
        $('.cliocont').fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 409) {
        $('.cliocont').fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
    }
});
```

Is there a reason why this code does not seem to work? Whenever the else if statement the code works, but whenever it is added the content doesn't appear or hide.

Thanks,
Nathan Niamehr

Comment: (offtopic) You have a 'stall' point at `409`. Use just: `< 409` in the second one.

Comment: Thanks, @RokoC.Buljan included that in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is more proper, this includes the time locks for two animations -- do remove the console.log(...) calls:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var animateTrainer1 = true;
            var animateTrainer2 = true;
            $(window).scroll(function () {

                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

                if (scrollTop > 500 && animateTrainer1) {
                    animateTrainer1 = false;
                    console.log("animated trainer 1");
                    Animations.toPosition("#trainer1", 0, -100, 4000);
                }

                if (scrollTop > 800 && animateTrainer2) {
                    animateTrainer2 = false;
                    console.log("animated trainer 2");
                    Animations.toPosition("#trainer2", 100, 340, 4000);
                }

            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Added `.stop()` to prevent animation fade errors
 and a boolean flag `var io` to prevent unnecessary animations:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/exoyab/81/edit)*

```
var $cc = $('.cliocont'),
    io  = false; // flag // compare booleans

$(window).scroll(function () {
  
   var is409 = $(window).scrollTop() >= 409; // boolean
   if (io != is409){
      io = is409;
      $cc.stop().fadeTo(800, is409?1.0:0.5);
   }
 
});
```

`is409 ? 1.0 : 0.5` is a [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and
it's a shorthand for the `if` statement;
`boolean ? ifTrue : else ;`

Comment: It should be noted that you probably only want to do the animation *once* and not for every pixel where the scroll occurs. As such, you need to add a locking function that ensures the call only occurs once.