# Image movement and placement depending on scroll page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to get help for an a test site I want to make. I tried asking previously, but was put down because I was told it was asked before, which it really was not.

Here is my problem. I want to be able to go to a page, and have an image to float or move up from the middle or top and then stay there...UNTIL the user scrolls down and then I want the image to go to a specific place with text next to it. i have search this site and google and many other tutorials and have not seen what I am looking for. I was given this link: [How to animate an object depending on page scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528713/how-to-animate-an-object-depending-on-page-scroll-position) which is sort of what I am describing, but I need the image to move to a certain spot when scrolling, not turn into a specific color or transparency. I also found this: [javascript mousewheel image scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131197/javascript-mousewheel-image-scroll/18131335#18131335)  - however, this is also not really what I mean, it is a great effect, but I need the image to move. Furthermore, this is not a background image, this is an image that is above all on the page and is clickable. Not a window or background effect.

Do I use something like scrolly for this? for example:

```
stop().animate({"top":(window.scrollY)
```

I tried this and it moves so smoothly, but I cannot get it to stay there at the spot when scrolling to that specific spot, if you keep scrolling down, the image continues to scroll down.

Or is this a better method:

```
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
     var a = $(window).height() - 100;
     $('#scrolling').animate({
```

However, I cannot get it to work, it doesn't go back up to top when scrolling back to the top.

Any thoughts on how I would get the image to float in to the center or top or even on the sides and then move to a spot when scrolling down? Am I on the right path or am I totally going about this incorrectly?

I thought I could do this in HMTL5 with animation protocols, but I do not think I can acheive that, and I know CSS3 is robust, but it is also very choppy, so I think JQuery or JavaScript is the way to go, and I can get it partially working but not fully. Any thoughts?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) on the other hand says that Javascript is choppy, and CSS animations are the way to go.

Comment: @Mr Lister - Really? I have never really seen JavaScript be choppy. It is usually smooth. Do you think I should go with CSS then? I am not to well versed in CSS3 animations, I could give it a go. Do you think I am on the right track or wrong track?